Retrieving Locations at a Specific Address
I am working with Node.js library @googlemaps/places and would like to retrieve all locations (e.g., businesses, restaurants, offices) at a specific address.
However, when I send an address to the API, I only receive the address itself or the associated street. I couldn’t find a function similar to the "Places at this location" feature available in Google Maps in the API documentation.
Is there a way to retrieve all locations (places) at a given address via the API? If so, could you please provide guidance or point me to the relevant feature in your API?
